# Radon-Nikodym derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

In Folland's Real Analysis proposition 3.6

Suppose that $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite signed measure and $\mu, \lambda$ are $\sigma$-finite positive measures on $(X, \mathcal{M})$ such that $\nu \ll \mu$ and $\mu \ll \lambda$. Then, the following hold:

(a) If $g \in L^{1}(\nu),$ then $g(d \nu / d \mu) \in L^{1}(\mu)$ (the function $g$ multiplied by $d \nu / d \mu$) and
$$
\int g d \nu=\int g \frac{d \nu}{d \mu} d \mu
$$

I don't understand why if $g \in L^{1}(\nu),$ then $g(d \nu / d \mu) \in L^{1}(\mu)$, as $d\nu / d \mu$ only need to be an extended $\mu$-integrable function, which mean that at least one of $\int (d\nu / d \mu)^+$ and $\int (d\nu / d \mu)^-$ is finite,so it is possible one of $\int (d\nu / d \mu)^+$ and $\int (d\nu / d \mu)^-$ is infinite, but for $L^1$, we need both $\int (d\nu / d \mu)^+$ and $\int (d\nu / d \mu)^-$ be finite?

Comment: It's not $g(d\nu/d\mu)$, it's $g$ multiplied by $d\nu/d\mu$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Radon–Nikodym derivative is *not* extended; it's always finite-valued.

Since $ \nu $ is $ \sigma $-finite, write $ X $ as a countable union $ X = \bigcup \limits _ { i = 1 } ^ \infty X _ i $ where $ \nu ( X _ i ) < \infty $ for each $ i $.  Then the derivative is finite on each $ X _ i $; if it were infinite on any subset of $ \mu $-positive measure, then $ \nu ( X _ i ) $ would be infinite.  (And since it's only defined up to $ \mu $-a.e. equality, if it's infinite on a $ \mu $-null set, we can redefine it to be finite there.)  And so the derivative is finite on all of $ X $.

But I think that if you check the fine print in any statement and proof of the Radon–Nikodym Theorem, then you'll see that the derivative that it constructs is finite-valued.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $
\int g d \nu=\int g \frac{d \nu}{d \mu} d \mu$

holds for all non-negative measurable functions $g$ . This is proved by the standard simple function approximation argument. Hence, $\int |g \frac{d \nu}{d \mu} d \mu
| d\mu=\int |g| \frac{d \nu}{d \mu} d \mu=\int |g| d\nu <\infty$.